# How to get UITableView to be positioned within the safe area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get my UITableView to be positioned within the safe area but it doesn't seem to be working and I do not know why.  I trying to do this programatically.

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var margin: UILayoutGuide!
    var tableDataSource: [userFolderObject]!
    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setup()
    }

    private func setup(){
        margin = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        tableDataSource = MockData.UITableDateSource
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor).isActive = true 

        /* I have also tried the below code
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        */

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        if section == 0{
            label.text = "Search PubMed"
        }else{
            label.text = "My Folders"
        }
        return label
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove all of your setup code that attempts to mess with the margins of the table view. That is all done for you by default in a `UITableViewController`.

Since your issue is only with the layout of your custom section header views, you need to fix how you have implemented those views.

Like cells, you should use reusable header/footer views and your header/footer view should extend `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. This will ensure proper margins by defaults and it already provides a standard `textLabel` you can set. No need to create your own `UILabel`.

As shown in the documentation for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` you should register a class. Then in `viewForHeader` you should dequeque the header view and then set its `textLabel` as needed.

If you don't actually need anything but a plain old section label, then don't implement `viewForHeader`. Instead, implement `titleForHeader`. Much simpler.